# ExtJS4 - Responsive layout and components

Tags: css, extjs, responsive-design, sencha-touch, extjs4.1

We have developed an application in Extjs 4. 
We want to make it responsive.

Our Goal is : 
When we resize window , it should automatically adjust components and update layout accordingly.

Can anyone guide me in correct direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: nice question if you find any solution just forward me that one.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically you have only two options:

1) Make your own implementation using ExtJS and maybe bootstrap framework. Some clues you can get from this post and the following ExtJS 5 components:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?253766-Responsive-UI-and-ExtJS&p=1037960&viewfull=1#post1037960

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Responsive
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.plugin.Responsive

2) You can migrate to Ext JS 5. I know it's painful but if you want to keep developing your application, this will be your best option as ExtJS 6 is officially announced.

The best place to start would be this guide: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/whats_new/5.0/extjs_upgrade_guide.html

Comment: I think rishabh has mentioned that he wants solution in ExtJS4 & its not just painful to migrate but its catastrophe. so its good if we can find something awe full for specific ExtJS4 nothing else.

Comment: Then the only option is to write something based on my first suggestion.

Comment: thanks baidaly for your reply. can you give some idea to create responsive layout or may be any kind of column layout so we can use it for responsive structure?

Comment: Are you using 4.1 or 4.2? I'll try to create an example but it'll take time.

Comment: thanks baidaly for your effort. I am using ExtJS 4.1

Answer (score 1):

You can compare with new ExtJs 5.0.0 framework, or give a try on bootstrap framework with ExtJs 4